# Open View depending on role (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have several roles for users in my website.

I need to return different view on user role.

Now I have call View default way

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

But I need this: if user has Admin role I return `Index.cshtml`.
If it has user role I need to return `IndexUser.cshtml`.

How I can realize it?

**UPDATE**

I tried to realize it like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) 
        {
            return View();
        }

        if (User.IsInRole("Test"))
        {
            return View("IndexProjectManager");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

But it always going to `return View`

Comment: You can use filters for this. You can check for a role and the redirect accordingly

Comment: `[Authorize (Roles="admin")]` this one? @kritikaTalwar

Comment: You can create you own filter

Comment: @eugene how to you get to the Index action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do itin view then you can use below to redirect to another view:

`return RedirectToAction("Reporting", "ReportManagement", new { area="Admin" })`

I mean on the basis of condition as below:

```
if (isAdmin)
{ 
    return view();//supposing it is the view for admin
} 
else
{ 
    return RedirectToAction("Reporting", "ReportManagement", new { area="Admin" })
}
```

Comment: Thank's

It helps

Answer (score 1):

```
if (User.IsInRole("admin")) //whatever your admin role is called
{
    return View();
}

if (User.IsInRole("user"))
{
    return View("IndexUser");
}

return View("Whatever"); //or RedirectToAction(...)
```

Comment: Okay, but if I had for example 3 roles?

Comment: @eugene you could also write User.IsInRole("x") || User.IsInRole("y")

Comment: Not works. It always redirect me to admin View

I think because of last return View. But if I delete it, I have return error

Comment: Update my post.

Comment: @eugene i dont know what your roles are called so you need to replace the role names accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm basing this on assuming how your Roles work...apologies if this isn't quite appropriate.

You could make it so that `Index` View is the lowest level (basic) user view then have suffixes appended to each 'higher' role's views.

That way, you could do something like this:

```
[Authorize] //make sure they're logged in
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string _viewSuffix = "";

    //this bit would have to be hierarchical - high to low - so you have a degradation of what the view offers...
    if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) 
    {
        _viewSuffix = "Admin";
    }
    else if(User.IsInRole("Test"))
    {
        _viewSuffix = "Test";
    }
    //...and so on

    return View("Index" + _viewSuffix);
}
```